# Using p5.js, when using a function inside of draw, how do I make it only go once?

Tags: javascript, input, p5.js

I'm using p5.js for a project of mine, and I don't understand how I can check if a key is pressed, and when it is, run a function, but only once.

I have the `keyIsDown` function inside of `draw`, because I need to constantly be checking for input, but when a key is pressed, run my function once. But after this function runs once, I need it to be ready for me to press the key, or a different key, again.

It is currently running the function proportional to the framerate, I want it to run once per key click. Some pseudocode would look like:

```
function ABC () {
    console.log("1")
}

draw () {
    when key(1) is pressed:
        function ABC()
}
```

And out would output "1" but 5-30 times, even if I click the key as fast as I can. The problem is that `draw()` is constantly looping so when it checks `keyPressed`, it registers it as pressed a few times.

How can I ensure the function only runs once per button click, still continues to wait for another button click, but runs the function work?

EDIT:

I have tried both:

```
function keyTyped() {
  console.log("a")
  if (key === 'a') {
    console.log("a")
  }
}
```

and

```
function keyPressed() {
  console.log("a")
  if (key === 'a') {
    console.log("a")
  }
}
```

and nothing happens, no matter what key I press. Something should go to the console, but nothing is.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't get this. I copied what I added to the edit to a new window of the editor, and it worked perfectly. I copied this code back to the code I'm working on, and it doesn't work at all there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `keyPressed()` function:

```js
function draw() {
  // stuff that happens 60 times per second
}

function keyPressed() {
  // stuff that happens once per key press
}
```

You can find more info in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Another approach would be to create a boolean variable that tracks whether you've already handled the key press.

Comment: But keycode (Used in keypressed in refrence) only detects special keys right? I need it to detect the "1" key

Comment: @joelanbanks3 You can use the `key` or `keyCode` variables, depending on which key you're looking for. Check the reference for more information on both.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I did not have the Setup function, as I was just testing logic. Didn't realize that was necessary to use the KeyPressed. All I did was add it without any parameters, works great!